# How to dynamically Map the Fieldsets in SpringBatch during file reading?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have the requirement to read the file  with the help of spring batch . But at the time of reading it requires LineMapper . If columns type of file doesn't match it gives error

I want to do it dynamically or skip that step how do i do that?

```
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5" });
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<InputStream> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<InputStream>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(InputStream.class);
        fieldSetMapper.setStrict(false);
        DefaultLineMapper<InputStream> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<InputStream>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
        setLineMapper(lineMapper);
```

Another thing i want

I am using FlatFileItemreader to read the files . This file may be csv,xml,txt format . I want the spring batch reader to dynamically identify the file format and process it accordingly . Can we do that

Answer (score 1):

your question could be related with this existing one [multiple-files-of-different-data-structure-formats-as-input-in-spring-batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117045/multiple-files-of-different-data-structure-formats-as-input-in-spring-batch). Spring Batch doesn't provide a generic ItemReader out of the box to support to read different kind of formats at once. It is possible to use **MultiResourceItemReader** as described in Spring Batch documentation here [multi file input reader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#multiFileInput) but only for input files with the same format. In your case you have to decide which kind of reader you want to use depending on which input file format you have. For example you could try in your job configuration class create your own ItemReader something similar with this

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<YourDomainClass> itemReader(
            @Value("#{jobParameters}") Resource inputFile) {

        //your logic here
        String fileName = inputFile.getFilename();
        if (isCsv(inputFile)) {
            return csvItemReader(inputFile);
        } else if(isXml(inputFile)){
            return xmlItemReader(inputFile);
        } else {
           ...
        }
    }

    //CSV ItemReader
    public FlatFileItemReader<YourDomainClass> csvItemReader(Resource inputFile) {

        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<YourDomainClass>()
                .name("csvItemReader")
                .delimited()
                .names(new String[] {"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"})
                .targetType(YourDomainClass.class)
                .resource(inputFile)
                .build();
    }

    //XML ItemReader
    public ItemReader<YourDomainClass> xmlItemReader(Resource inputFile) {

        ...
    }

    //JSON ItemReader
    public ItemReader<YourDomainClass> jsonItemReader(Resource inputFile) {

        ...
    }
```

Hope it helps you.